# Strange js regexp behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, firebug

I've the folowing code:

```
$.get(TASK_FILE, function(data) {
    lines = data.split("\n");
    var place = /@[\S]*/g
    var category = /\+[\S]*/g
    lin = []
    for(line in lines)
    {
    var str = lines[line]
    var res = category.exec(str)
    console.log(res)
        if(res != null) 
    {
        str = str.replace(place, "");
        //lin[res[0]] = str;
    }

    }

    var res = category.exec("Czytanie +rosyjski @komunikacja @podrecznik")
    console.log(res)
```

The TASK_FILE is the url of text file which contains:

```
Zadania z fizyki +mFizyka @dom
Czytanie +rosyjski @komunikacja @podrecznik
```

As you can see I want to get the lisnes of the file that has "+something" and I want to save this something to the var but firebug output really suprise me:
[image]

The first line of file is handeld correctly but the next is not. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, thank you. Now evrything working as I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `g` (global) flag in combination with `exec` makes `exec` continue its search from the end of the last match. This can of course cause anomalies when you switch the search subject in the meantime. Just go with the `match` function on strings instead:

```
str.match(category);
```